# AngularJS - Waiting for $$phase to become null

Tags: angularjs

In my directive, I make an API call, get the data and render it. While the render is happening, (i.e. `$digest` is running), I want to wait and then do something.

This was my implementation, which doesn't work:

```
// Assume I'm in the callback function of the $resource
function(response) {
   // $scope.templates now needs to render
   $scope.templates = (_.isEmpty(response.warning)) ? response.data : [];

   var s = $scope.$watch('$$phase', function(v) {
       if (_.isNull(v)) {
          NowRunMyNextAwesomeAction()
          // Silent the $watch
          s();
       }
   });
}
```

When I `console.log(v)` just inside the `$watch`, it logs `$diget` and then nothing else. Why? I thought that something else might be happening, so I tried to log `$$phase` with a `$timeout` after 1s, and it shows `null`. So it is definitely not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found "a" solution; I don't know if this good practice or not, but it relies on using `$timeout`. I was under the impression that using timers in Javascript is not recommended?

Anyway, here is how to do this:

```
// Assume I'm in the callback function of the $resource
function(response) {
   // $scope.templates now needs to render
   $scope.templates = (_.isEmpty(response.warning)) ? response.data : [];

   $timeout(function(){
       NowRunMyNextAwesomeAction();
   });
}
```

Note that the `$timeout` has a delay of zero. For more information, please [see here](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering).